# Which design pattern is it if any for providing a general logger interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a library where I want to use a logger but I don't have (and cannot) create any interface for it because I'll be using it on different systems that have nothing in common (and won't have). So this won't work:

```
public void Foo(ILogger logger, ... other params)
{
    logger.Info(...):
}
```

To overcome this problem and to make it possible to use any logging framework a particular system is using I came up with this solution:

I created a class that would provide delegates for the logging methods:

```
public class LoggerProxy
{
    private Action<string> _info;

    public LoggerProxy(Action<string> info)
    {
        _info = info;
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        if (_info != null) _info(message);
    }
}
```

And would use it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var logger = new LoggerProxy(SomeLoggingSystem.Info);
    Foo(logger, ...);
}

public void Foo(LoggerProxy logger, ... other params)
{
    logger.Info(...):
}
```

I call it proxy but I'm just curious if it is really a proxy or maybe an adapter or still something else. I read the answers to [How do the Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge Patterns differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adapter-and-bridge-patterns-differ?rq=1) but I cannot say that I can for sure say that any of those names is fine here.

Comment: I don't know... log4net uses the interface mechanism and works for many different logging targets. Log4Net is very good, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I'm not reinventing anything ;-) I just need to able to log on different systems where each of them uses somehow a different logging system, enterprise library, nlog or log4net or still other things so I do not have any common interface but to create such a _proxy_ things and this question is not about which logging is the best :P

Comment: Ah (a thankless task). You're effectively not wrapping the underlying logger then, but the underlying system. A Facade or Adapter seems the most obvious as you're not just passing your log calls to another logger that uses the same data. You're wrapping them up in your logger to provide a higher-level 'view' of the logging subsystems. Many design patterns provide the same functionality with only minor differences, so don't think of one of them as "the" sole solution and the others are unsuitable. Many of them will be good for what you want. Just pick one and use it.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja no, you are perfectly right, I was wondering whether it is any of the _famous_ patterns but I wasn't able to definitely associate it with any of them. I thought it might be a proxy but none of the definitions provided in the other question matches to 100% here. Ok, then I think I'll have to live with a _simple class_ :)

Comment: Looks like functional solution, so standard patterns won't apply here. I'd stay with 'proxy' in class name though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided code `LoggerProxy` is just a simple class not following any famous pattern, saying that closest pattern I would compare it to is [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (not that I recommend using it at least yet).

Since you seem to be after a well designed logging interface, I would recommend you to go through answers in this SO post,

[Is it a good practice to have logger as a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472678/is-it-a-good-practice-to-have-logger-as-a-singleton)

Back to your `LoggerProxy` class with information provided it doesn't seems to be following OOP approach - just simple procedural programming I would say.

Comment: This has nothing in common with the singleton pattern apart from being source code.

Comment: @nvoigt I know that.... which is why I said it's just a simple class.. where did I said it has something common with singleton ?